# Invoking UI delegate causes UI to be hidden

Tags: .net, multithreading, user-interface, delegates, invoke

Suppose I have thread 1, the main window UI thread and thread 2, a login UI thread that is modal form.

Now thread 1 executes a piece of code and wants to change a UI element in the login form so it invokes a delegate to change something in thread 2. But when it does so, the login form becomes hidden behind the main window and there's no way for me to bring it back. Selecting it on the taskbar doesn't do anything and writing "Activate()" at the end of the invoked method doesn't do anything either.

How can I keep thread 2's UI from becoming hidden?

Thanks

Comment: Also, when there's only one thread, using ShowDialog on the login form, it would block the main window and force the login form to be in front. This is no longer true if I have 2 threads and I can close the main window while the login form is still open. Can I replicate the behavior of a single thread application with 2 threads?

Comment: Do you want the "blocking" (modal) behavior? Maybe you could create the second thread inside the login form, using BackgroundWorker or something like that. Disable all controls on the login dialog, perform any asynchronous tasks that you need (logging in?) then when the BackgroundWorker completes it either unlocks the login form and says "sorry, try again" or if successful the form just closes and lets you in to the main application.

Comment: If I did so, then the login UI would be the same as the main UI right? Suppose I need independent UI threads but dependent UI behaviors. ie, I want form 2 to draw regardless of how busy form 1 is but I don't want 2 icons on the taskbar. I also don't want it to be possible for one form to be shown without the other.
Is this possible on separate threads?

Comment: Seems like you have a bad pattern going if form 1 may be 'busy'. It is good practice to show all your forms in the same thread and to do any asynchronous operations using worker threads. Rather than creating a separate thread for form 2, could you create the separate thread for the work form 1 is doing, then immediately ShowDialog() form 2? You can stop form 2 from showing in the taskbar by setting Form.ShowInTaskbar to false.

Comment: Ok, I see the convention now. I'll try that. It's just that if I did all the operations in a different thread, I'd have to be using Invoke() everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [Focus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx) on your login form after you invoke to update the main window. Also it may help to set the parent window of the login form to be the main window when you display it.

(in your main UI class)

```
using (YourLoginForm f = new YourLoginForm()){

    YourLoginForm.Show(this)
}
```

Another approach may be to use [ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx) instead of [Show()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show.aspx), and have your login form return a different [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx) depending on whether the login was successful or not. ShowDialog() should automatically set your login form to be modal and have the focus.

Answer (score 0):

wow.... self pwn. k, the disappearing second window thing is a non-question

But the question in the comment still stands....
When I do ShowDialog in a second thread, how do I prevent the new window from acting separately from the main window? ie I don't want the user to minimize the main window while it's behind the second window. If another program comes up on top and hides everything, clicking the main window's icon in the taskbar has to bring up the second window with it etc

Comment: Don't add an answer to your own question unless it's actually an answer.  Clarifying information should be added as a comment or edited into your original question.